# Can we apply landing minimum with ALS when ALS is available with low intensity only?

Tags: faa-regulations, landing, instrument-flight-rules, runways

Can we apply landing minimums with ALS when the ALS is available with "low intensity" only?

For example, the following NOTAM is issued at [KABQ](http://airnav.com/airport/KABQ):

> !ABQ 05/270 ABQ RWY 03 ALS OUT OF SERVICE EXC LOW INTST ON CONS
>   1705302145-1706151800EST

In this case, is the applied landing minimum for ILS RWY03 VIS 1/2 or VIS 3/4?

I'm talking about part 121 operator.

Comment: Can you link to an actual instrument approach plate? I can't see 1/2 or 3/4 anywhere on the KABQ 03 plates, so it isn't clear what you're looking at and if those plates include any restrictions based on lighting. And are you asking about part 91, 135 or 121? The general rule on approaches is that part 91 has no restrictions beyond what's on the plate, whereas 135 and 121 have some additional rules and also have to follow their OpSpecs (as approved by the FAA).

Comment: Thank you for your advice.I'm looking at Jeppsen chart.And I'm talking about a scheduled commercial airliner.I can' t add link because Jeppesen chart isn't free to publish.According to [TERPS page 3-16](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/FAA_Order_8260.3C.pdf), if HAT is 200ft and non-ALS, applied landing minimum is VIS 3/4.

Comment: The TERPS don't deal with LIALS at all -- they punt that to 1.4.2 on nonstandard IFPs, which requires a special study.  Yet, there's no FDC NOTAM out adjusting the SIAPs at the airport. WTFAA?

Answer (score 3):

The ILS to RWY 3 at ABQ [(ILS RWY 3 ABQ plate)](http://155.178.201.160/d-tpp/1802/00012IL3.PDF) shows a required RVR of 1800  (not vis in sm) with everything working.  Using the inop component table (no special provisions for this in Operations Specs) shows a **required increase to 4000** RVR with the MALSR (ALS) inop. [(look at table)](http://www.pilotnav.com/static/frntmatter.pdf)

The fact is that the "LOW INTST ON CONS" (low intensity on continuously) does not provide any benefit since the MALSR (ALS) is shown (by NOTAM) as being out of service.

This is the way I understand the issue.